# How tell hyperref to insert a "target" in the resulting \href

Tags: hyperref

I am using the `hyperref` package to insert links to websites in my documents.

The Adobe reader opens a  new tab for each link in the PDF, and that is what I want.

Next I want to get the same behavior when I generate HTML using some LaTeX to HTML converter. I am using plasTeX.

How do I tell `hyperref` via `\href{site}{text}`that I want the HTML code to have a `target="blank"` inside the

```html
<a href="site">text</a>
```

in the resulting HTML?

Comment: Please remember that a lot of users does not like this. They like to choose for them self. At my work our CMS started out using `target="blank"` for all external links on homepage. They have now removed it because people complained.

Comment: If you use `tex4ht` there's a solution [urls - tex4ht: configure href to open in new tab - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245739/tex4ht-configure-href-to-open-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: it can't be done.

`hyperref` can open new browser tabs/windows if the target is another PDF document. This is done using the `\href` feature `pdfnewwindow`. No similar feature exists in `hyperref` to open new tabs\windows for http or https web addresses. See [Make hyperref links open in new browser window for easier navigation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200577/62165) for clarification and further information.

Comment: To be more precise, if I read correctly the PDF 1.7 specification of  `URI actions` (links to the web), there is no option to affect how such links are opened.  So hyperref cannot do anything about that.  Of course, using Javascript works but only in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: I think this answer might be correct but for the wrong question. OP is generating a **HTML document** using e.g. plasTeX, not `hyperref`.