# How to get \url{} and \href{} displayed identically

Tags: hyperref, urls, links

I would like the output of `\url{}` and `\href{}` displayed identically. I have changed the color for both to be `blue`, but it appears as if a different for is being used as well:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}


\begin{document}
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com}{www.yahoo.com}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Manuel I don't quite understand your comment. Wasn't that the question? That is, why they are using different fonts?

Comment: @Manuel Oh. I see. I read 'different for' as a typo for 'different font'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`url` changes the font but you can set it to default to serif to match `\href`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\urlstyle{rm}

\begin{document}
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com}{www.yahoo.com}
\end{document}
```

[image: url styling]

Note that `\urlstyle{}` is from [url](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) which `hyperref` is loading. (You can use `url` without `hyperref` - something I often do, in fact.) I can't see anywhere this is really explained in `hyperref`'s documentation but I only searched the PDF manual and there is a lot more of it so no doubt it is covered somewhere.

## Update

If you would prefer the style produced by `\href` to match the `\url` default - or if you would like both of them to use a different style, such as sans serif - you can use `\url{}` to format the link text produced by `\href{}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\urlstyle{sf}% sans for a change

\begin{document}
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com}{\url{www.yahoo.com}}

\urlstyle{tt}% back to url's default

url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com}{\url{www.yahoo.com}}

\end{document}
```

[image: More url styles...]

Comment: Aswesome. Just wondering is there a `\hrefstyle{}` equivalent?  Interestingly `\urlstyle` is not mentioned in the `hyperref` documentation.

Comment: @PeterGrill Honestly, I have no idea. I just happened to know that `url` changes the font to the default `tt` family. I have generally used `\url` to style the text within the `\href` command or wrapper. Although I assume I originally did that because I couldn't do it with `hyperref` alone, that was quite a while ago.

Comment: @PeterGrill Add `\listfiles` and look at the output. I am pretty sure you will find `url` listed among the packages. `hyperref.sty` includes `\RequirePackage{url}` but it is buried in code I don't understand. EDIT: Yes, I get `url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.`. `\urlstyle` is from that package.

Comment: @PeterGrill I've edited to explain where the `\urlstyle` command is coming from since this is not really at all obvious.

Comment: `\urlstyle` is a feature of package `url`, which is loaded by `hyperref`. There is no `\hrefstyle`, because the second argument of `\href` can contain arbitrary stuff including images.

Comment: Downside of using `\url` inside `\href` is that the link dies, i.e. clicking on it does nothing. The solution with `\nolinkurl` mentioned in the other answer works better.

Comment: @JorisMeys No it doesn't. All of the links in my example work, including the ones which use `\url` inside the second argument of `\href`.

Comment: @cfr I should have been more specific. Downside of using `\url` inside `\href` in a beamer context is that the link dies, at least for me it did. Which is why I needed `\nolinkurl` to keep them working.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 12):

The second argument of `\href` is arbitrary text. If the text should appear as in `\url`, then `\nolinkurl` can be used, that acts as `\url` without the link part, which is already provided by `\href`.

The font can be changed via `\urlstyle`, see the documentation of package `url`

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}


\begin{document}
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com/}{\nolinkurl{www.yahoo.com}}

\medskip
\urlstyle{sf}
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com/}{\nolinkurl{www.yahoo.com}}

\medskip
\urlstyle{rm}
url: \url{www.yahoo.com}

href: \href{http://www.yahoo.com/}{\nolinkurl{www.yahoo.com}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201952/62165. It might solve your problem. It is based on \href but you could use it as a \url replacement by making the two input parameters the same, ie, \click{www.yahoo.com}{www.yahoo.com}. Aternatively you could modify the \click command to take only one parameter. It doesn't change the background font, which is probably what you are trying to achieve.  It ignores all \hyperref defaults.