# How to open footnote url link in new tab (Overleaf)?

Tags: overleaf

When I click on the url footnote link, the page is loading on the same tab as the pdf.

What should I do for opening in new tab?

Here's an example of usage `\url` command:

`\footnotetext{\framebox[8cm]{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation}}}`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE ! // If I understand your question correctly, it's a matter of your browser, not of Latex or .pdf . Usually you can click with the richt mouse button and select sth. like "Open link in new Tab", depending on your browser and operating system.

Comment: pdf has nothing to control this. This is a matter of the pdf viewer/browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But there is any way to modify the `\url` command from overleaf to open the link in new tab by default by clicking the left mouse button?

Comment: no, as I said the pdf format has nothing here. Ask overleaf for an option.

Comment: ok, thank you :)

Comment: Which browser do you use? And do you use the built-in or the native pdf viewer in Overleaf (click menu on the top left, last option in the list)? I tried on Overleaf both in Firefox and Chrome with the built-in viewer and it opens the link in a new tab by default in both browsers, whereas with the native viewer it opens the link in the same tab.

Comment: on overleaf works fine. the problem is after you download the pdf and open it on browser (on the default pdf viewer of the browser) .. if i open the pdf on Adobe Acrobat, obviously there is no problem..the link will open on the browser without affecting the state of the pdf

Comment: @iulian for PDF.js in Firefox you can change the setting `pdfjs.externalLinkTarget` to `BLANK` in `about:config`, see for example https://superuser.com/questions/602615/how-to-configure-firefox-built-in-pdf-viewer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813373/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-a-new-tab-window. For Chrome I don't know how to change it.

Comment: okay, thanks :)