# Opening New PDF Tabs in Beamer Presentation

Tags: hyperref

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \hyperlink{causal.pdf\#page.44}{Section 4.2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

to open a new PDF document in my Beamer presentation. However, the new PDF document is opened in the same tab of my PDF reader, and it substitutes the current slides. I want to modify it so that clicking on the link displays the new PDF in a new tab. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Which pdf reader do you use? In my own viewer (Evince) I can open `\hyperlink` targets by right-click and then 'open in new window' or with middle click.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Pro

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611518/how-to-open-footnote-url-link-in-new-tab-overleaf#comment1529557_611518