# Modify the \url to open links in new tabs

Tags: urls, href

I am in LaTeX, and I just wrote this line:

`\renewcommand*{\url}[1]{\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}`.

But, it does not modify the behavior's of all my `\url` usages across the document, why? How can I make all `\url` to open in new tab(s)?

Comment: What do you mean "new tab"? Are you viewing the resulting PDF in a browser? Also please make a MWE

Comment: @user202729, yes, I am viewing it inside a web browser.

Comment: I believe the problem is not solvable [urls - Make hyperref links open in new browser window for easier navigation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200577/make-hyperref-links-open-in-new-browser-window-for-easier-navigation/201952#201952) (but there's a Firefox-specific solution there I didn't test)

Comment: (on further reading it may be possible to embed some JavaScript into the PDF but I don't know how portable the solution is either.)

Comment: So, if your pdf file contains 50 `\url` directives, you want the pdf browser program to *automatically* open 50 new tabs to display the web pages pointed to by the `\url` directives? Please confirm.

Comment: @Mico, if the reader clicks an link/url, it should open it in a new tab in the browser, and not redirect in the current tab and leave the open PDF.