# tex4ht: configure href to open in new tab

Tags: urls, tex4ht, htlatex

I'm working with tex4ht (htlatex) and I'm trying to put links into the page it generates. I'm trying to find a way to make it so that when I place a link in the page the link is generated to have the target set to `_blank`. The reason for this is so that I can have these links open in a new tab.
Here is the code I have in the `.tex` file

```
\href{www.somesite.com}{The text}
```

Here is what it generates

```
<a href="www.somesite.com">The text</a>
```

Here is what I'd like to generate for all links except the cross links

```
<a href="www.somesite.com" target="_blank">The text</a>
```

I know there are ways to use `\Configure` but I can't seam to make them change the code generation at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\href` command in the custom config file to include that attribute. Create file `hello.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\bgroup\let~\H@tilde%
  \Link[#1 target="_blank"]{}{}%
  {#2}\egroup\EndLink}%

\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

this definition is modified macro from `tex4ht` sources. `\let~\H@tilde` is needed for support urls in form of `something.com/~username/whatewer.html`.

`\Link` command has syntax:

```
\Link[external_url attributes]{internal link}{declare internal link} url text\EndLink
```

you don't need `internal link` and `declare internal link` in your case, it is useful for crossreferences in the document.

compile your document with

```
htlatex filename hello
```

and the result:

```xml
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" ><a 
href="http://www.somesite.com" target="_blank" >The text</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been searching for hours to try to find this solution.

Comment: @MarcusKarpoff you can find basic info about `tex4ht` configurations and available commands here: http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-infose1.html#x6-30002.1 (see also other pages of that document)

Comment: of course, you must know that you need to redefine the command you want to modify

Comment: In case anyone comes looking. I noticed that it didn't actually work for tildes still. After playing around I found a way to make them work. Just use \string~ and it will place a tilde in think link